# Access RDS security Group using Boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, rds

I am trying to fetch the security group attached to an RDS in AWS. It is not returning anything other than RDS name.
Need a way to get the security group attached to an RDS.

My current code->

```
rds_sg = conn2.get_all_dbinstances()

for r in rds_sg:
    sec = []
    sec = r.security_groups
    for s in sec:
        print s
```

This is not printing anything.

Comment: Could you post the code you are currently using as well as the response you are getting from RDS?

Comment: Done...sorry fr late reply :)

Comment: Are you using VPC?  If so, you will find the security groups with the attribute ``vpc_security_groups`` attribute rather than the ``security_groups`` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me (assumes a single RDS Instance but you can change that):

```
def get_db_info():

    rds_conn = boto.connect_rds2(profile_name=AWS_PROFILE)
    if not rds_conn:
        print(_red('Cannot connect to AWS.RDS'))
        return

    instances = rds_conn.describe_db_instances()
    if not instances:
        print(_red('No instances found'))
        return

    inst = instances['DescribeDBInstancesResponse']['DescribeDBInstancesResult']['DBInstances'][0]

    dbinfo = {}
    endpoint = inst['Endpoint']
    dbinfo['VPCSecurityGroupId'] = inst['VpcSecurityGroups'][0]['VpcSecurityGroupId']
    dbinfo['dbSecurityGroupName'] = inst['DBSecurityGroups'][0]['DBSecurityGroupName']

    print('')
    print(_blue('db Info ===========>\n'))
    for item in dbinfo:
        print(_green('%20s : %s' % (item, dbinfo[item])))
```

Instead of a profile_name, you can use the AWS Key/Secret arguments